# Android Studio - Display specific logcat messages in xml when a certain message appears in logcat

Tags: android-studio, logcat

How do I display a specific logcat message in the app itself. Let's say for every `power_partial_wake_State` message in logcat like the following:

`power_partial_wake_state: [0,*alarm*:android]`

I want to display the most recent `power_partial_wake_State` message in activity_main.xml. Basically, I want the app to do something when a specific log appears in logcat (in this case using power_partial_wake_state as an example).